# mail sent by access url but SMTP Connect() failed when run with batch file

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, gmail, phpmailer

I have a problem with batch file

if I access: `http://localhost:8080/cron/cron.php` 
I got email sent with message `Yeah, message send via Gmail`

this my `cron.php`

```
<?php   
require_once 'simplehtmldom\simple_html_dom.php';
require_once 'sites.php';
require_once 'send_mail.php';
ini_set('display_errors','on');
foreach ($site_list as $name => $link){
    $command = "C:\\Python27\\python C:\\webcheck\\webcheck.py -o C:\\wamp\\www\\cron\\reports\\$name $link";   
    $output =   shell_exec($command);   
    $log_file = "C:\\wamp\\www\\cron\\log.txt";
    $fh = fopen($log_file,'w') or die('can not open file');
    fwrite($fh, $output);
    fclose($fh);
}


/*Scan folder for reporting */
$path = 'C:\\wamp\\www\cron\\reports\\';
$msg = '';
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDir() && !$fileInfo->isDot()) {
        // Do whatever
        $webcheck = $fileInfo->getFilename() ;
        $html = file_get_html($path.$webcheck.'\\badlinks.html');
        $es = $html->find('div[class="content"]', 0);
        $msg .="<h2>BADLINKS $webcheck</h2>";             
        $msg .= $es->innertext; // Some Content 
    }
}

$subj = $_subj; 
$to = $_to;
$from = $_from;
$name = $_name;

if (smtpmailer($to, $from, $name, $subj, $msg)) {
    echo 'Yeah, message send via Gmail';
} else {
    if (!smtpmailer($to, $from, $name, $subj, $msg, false)) {
        if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
    } else {
        echo 'Yep, the message is send (after doing some hard work)';
    }
}

?>
```

But with this `cron.bat`

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php C:\wamp\www\cron\cron.php
```

I go to `cmd`and type `cron.bat`

I got messsage `Mail error: SMTP Connect() failed.`

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that cron jobs will be using the `PHP CLI`. And the `PHP CLI` uses a different `php.ini` file to Apache.

Make sure you have all the required extension activated within this other `php.ini file`.

I would imagine the `php_smtp` extension is not activated.

Ahh I see you are using WAMP so the `PHP CLI` version of the php.ini file will be in `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.ini`.

Where as the Apache version is in `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.x.y\bin\php.ini` if you need to compare which extension you have activated in Apache PHP to those not activated in the `PHP CLI`